# Visual Studio MSbuild rename file event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I am writing a extension for visual studio, which will automatically generate some JS file according to ascx code.

```
 public class JSCodeGenTask : Task
```

This Task is registered as a after-build task, which means it will be executed after every build. The class extends Task, and is registered in csproj.

```
   <Target Name="AfterBuild">
      <JSCodeGenTask FileNames="@(something)" outPath="@(somethingelse)" />
   </Target>
```

The problem is, I want to keep track of programmers renaming an ascx file, namely, I want the former name of that ascx file. Is there a way to access this information?

```
 public event RenamedEventHandler Renamed
```

I know renamed event can be used here, but I don't know how to register this event to Visual Studio -- .csproj. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I've found the solution

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166508%28VS.100%29.aspx

It should be implemented as a Custom Tool instead of MSbuild event. Examples can be found at

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SingleFileGenerator#BuildAndRun

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easer to write target. All you need is create appropriate `ItemGroup` with *.ascx files. You can grab them all (or with filter applied) from `Content`

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="GenerateScripts" />
<Target Name="GenerateScripts">
  <ItemGroup>    
       <AscxFiles Include="@(Content)" Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.ascx'" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <JSCodeGenTask FileNames="@(AscxFiles)" OutPath="$(OutPath)" />
</Target>
```